# CSS nth-of-type not selecting in order

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to use jQuery to add different classes to repeating `div` but it's not working as expected… Here's my JavaScript:

```
$('div.cake:nth-of-type(1n)').css('border-bottom', '3px solid red');
$('div.cake:nth-of-type(2n)').css('border-bottom', '3px solid blue');
$('div.cake:nth-of-type(3n)').css('border-bottom', '3px solid green');
$('div.cake:nth-of-type(4n)').css('border-bottom', '3px solid yellow');
```

And this is my HTML:

```
<section id="menu">

    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>Texty text lorem ipsum blah blah</p>

    <div class="cake">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/food/1/" />
        <span class="caption">Image 1 here</span></a>
    </div>

    <div class="cake">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/food/2/" />
        <span class="caption">Image 2 here</span></a>
    </div>

    <div class="cake">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/food/3/" />
        <span class="caption">Image 3 here</span></a>
    </div>

    <!-- And so on... -->

</section>
```

I expect the first `div` to have a border on the bottom in red, second `div` in blue, third in green, fourth in yellow, then red, blue, green, yellow, etc., but it doesn't quite work out. Here's a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7bLZ3/

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Works fine. What are you seeing?

Comment: The first 4 work.. then not for me

Comment: Have you tried in a different browser? Isn't `nth-of-type` a new adoption?

Comment: Be sure you are using jQuery 1.9 or later.  The `nth-of-type` wasn't implemented until that version.

Comment: @putvande please refer to the jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7bLZ3/ the first four `div`s have correct border colours (red, blue, green, yellow), then 5th `div` is red, 6th `div` is _green_ (should be blue), 7th `div` is _red_ (should be green), and 9th `div` is _green_ (should be red).

Comment: @Shaun yep I'm using 1.10.2.

Comment: Mate, the answer is below. Works :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use offsets:

```
$('div.cake:nth-of-type(4n+1)').css('border-bottom', '3px solid red');
$('div.cake:nth-of-type(4n+2)').css('border-bottom', '3px solid blue');
$('div.cake:nth-of-type(4n+3)').css('border-bottom', '3px solid green');
$('div.cake:nth-of-type(4n+4)').css('border-bottom', '3px solid yellow');
```

The reason for this is e.g. after setting 2n then the 4th item is set as well... then 4n will overwrite it and naturally it doesn't work properly. Not to mention that 1n will set them all and that 3n will set items 3 and 6 and this would overwrite the 3rd instance of the 2n.

Comment: @user2670854 That's ok. I understand - all the best.

Answer (score -2):

And, for anyone that does not have `nth-of-type()` support:

```
var btmColors = [];
btmColors[0] = 'red';
btmColors[1] = 'blue';
btmColors[2] = 'green';
btmColors[3] = 'yellow';
$('div.cake').css('border-bottom-width', '3px').css('border-bottom-style', 'solid').css ('border-bottom-color', function (i) {
        return btmColors[i % 4];
});
```

[js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/7bLZ3/5/)

Comment: that's not going to help the fundamental problem... did you look past the first 4 items?

Comment: Ah.. I see now. It gets hosed up.

Comment: @d'alar'cop You can remove your downvote. This is as valid an answer as yours.

Comment: @DevlshOne I have cast 0 downvotes on SO - it's bad form imo. So... not me. Sorry - I'll upvote you though why not. Cheers

Comment: @DevlshOne nice alternative by the way